# Better option than multiple SessionFactories for multiple datasets?

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory

I have an import app where the user hands me a dataset(s) (in my case a data-dump of a stackexchange site) and a table prefix, and I need to create the tables and import the data.

However the only way I can think of to import this in Hibernate is to have a dedicated SessionFactory for each dataset so I can have a specific NamingStrategy for SchemaExport and Session to use. Otherwise hibernate will get confused on which tables I'm talking about

Creating multiple SessionFactories seems like the wrong way to use Hibernate though. It also seems like a lot of overhead and memory usage.

Does anyone know of a way to use a single SessionFactory in this case?